# How to make a function template the least priority during ADL?

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a problem where I'd like to provide a generic version of a function `foo` which may only be applied when there is absolutely no other match for an invocation. How can I modify the following code such that `last_resort::foo` is a worse match for `derived::type` than `base::foo`? I'd like to find a solution which does not involve modifying the definition of  `bar` and which would preserve the type of the argument of `last_resort::foo`.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace last_resort
{

template<typename T> void foo(T)
{
  std::cout << "last_resort::foo" << std::endl;
}

}

template<typename T> void bar(T)
{
  using last_resort::foo;
  foo(T());
}

namespace unrelated
{

struct type {};

}

namespace base
{

struct type {};

void foo(type)
{
  std::cout << "base::foo" << std::endl;
}

}

namespace derived
{

struct type : base::type {};

}

int main()
{
  bar(unrelated::type()); // calls last_resort::foo
  bar(base::type());      // calls base::foo
  bar(derived::type());   // should call base::foo, but calls last_resort::foo instead

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last_resort::foo` can be removed from the overload set with `disable_if`. The idea is to disable `last_resort::foo(T)` if `foo(T)` is otherwise well-formed. This causes `last_resort::foo(T)` to be the worst match for `foo`:

```
namespace test
{

template<typename T> struct has_foo { ... };

}

namespace last_resort
{

template<typename T>
  struct disable_if_has_foo
    : std::enable_if<
        !test::has_foo<T>::value
      >
{};

template<typename T>
  typename disable_if_has_foo<T>::type foo(T)
{
  std::cout << "last_resort::foo" << std::endl;
}

}
```

The output:

```
$ g++ last_resort.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
last_resort::foo
base::foo
base::foo
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535464/sfinae-and-detecting-if-a-c-function-object-returns-void/5553460#5553460) describes how to build a solution for checking for the existence of a function (`foo`) returning `void`.

Answer (score 3):

This would be about as bad as it gets:

```
struct badParam { template <typename T> badParam(T t) { } };
namespace last_resort {
  void foo(badParam, int dummy = 0, ...) {
    std::cout << "last_resort::foo" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

You've got a user-defined conversion, a defaulted parameter and an unused ellipsis.

[edit]

Slight variant, to save `T` I moved the user-defined conversion to the dummy parameter:

```
struct badParam { 
    badParam() { }
    operator int() { return 42; }
};
namespace last_resort {
  template <typename T> void foo(T t, int dummy = badParam(), ...) {
    std::cout << "last_resort::foo" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that adding just the ```badParam``` is enough to demote it, but it erases the type of ```T``` in the conversion.

Comment: Well, for a last resort case, you can't generally rely on T anyway, because you get all the weird types. But saving it is hard. Template Argument Deduction doesn't produce those user-defined conversions.

Comment: Ancient post, but random thought: How about using the original `badParam`, but making `badParam` a template type with a template argument value pointer to the actual function to invoke, which it does so in its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much about it. Both foo functions are in the overload set. But your last_resort one is a better match simply because it does not require a conversion unlike base::foo for derived::type(). Only in the case where two candidates are "equally good" judging by the parameters and possible conversions, a non-template is preferred.

Comment: That's true, but I wonder if there is a way to introduce a "hidden" conversion into foo by augmenting it with some extra parameters with default values?

Comment: I don't think it'll work. From what I can tell the "best" you can get is an ambiguity so that compilation fails. But maybe, I'm missing something, too.

Comment: The solution seems to be to decorate ```last_resort::foo```'s return type with something like ```disable_if_foo_exists<T>::type```, which would use SFINAE to check for a free ```foo``` function. If one exists, ```last_resort::foo``` would get removed from the overload set.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an overload of `bar` for type `derived::type` after the declaration of `derived::type`. This can be in `namespace derived` or not.

```
void bar(derived::type)
{
  foo(derived::type());
}
```